# Count Distinct Staff Ref Nos of those who have 1 or 2 or 3 records

Tags: reporting-services, count

I am trying to build a column chart that would count distinct Staff Ref Nos of those who have 1 or 2 or 3 records.

As an example the included table shows 3 distinct Staff Ref Numbers next to 3 columns, one for each academic year, showing if they have a record (1 for yes) in any of the 3 years.

[image: table]

I would like to be able to count number of Staff who have 1 record, 2 records or 3 records, please.

I tried

```
=CountDistinct(IIF(Sum(Fields!NoofOTrecordsin2122.Value+Fields!NoOTrecordsin2223.Value+Fields!NoofOTrecordsin2324.Value)=1,Fields!StaffRef.Value,Nothing))
```

I was expecting to get a number of distinct Staff Ref Nos of those with 1 record, but got this "The Y expression for the chart ‘Chart6’ has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function.  The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing group, the name of a containing data region, or the name of a dataset"

| Staff Ref | No of OT in 2122 | No of OT in 2223 | No of OT in 2324 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15088 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 15088 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 15088 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 15157 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 15157 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 20622 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 20454 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 20454 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 20465 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 20465 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 20465 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

When I do a pivot of this data, it shows me that
2 Staff Refs (15088 and 20465) have 3 records (2122,2223,2324)
2 Staff Refs (15157 and 20454) have 2 records (2223,2324)
1 Staff Ref (20622) has 1 record (2324)

I would like to be able to count the number of Staff Refs who have 3 records, those with 2 records and those with 1 record.

Comment: Please supply data as text (preferably as a script to create the data) and your current report design. It's hard to guide you without more info. Also show what your expected output would look like.

Comment: Also, you probably need a bigger sample dataset, if I understood, the sample data would return a count of 1 for each of the 1, 2 and 3 record counts. This is probably easier to do in the dataset query to be honest but until I see the base data it's hard to say. If you have pivoted the data already, show the data unpivoted as it's usually easier to work with.

Comment: Hello Alan, thank you for looking into this. When you ask to supply data as text, what do you mean, pls? Sorry, I am new to this. How do I share the current report design with you? Thanks

Comment: You can share the design by just posting a screen shot. When supplying data, you can either create a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk) where you can script out the table creation and data population and then add a link to it, you can do the same thing directly in your question, or at the least type the data out using markdown (there are examples of how to do this such as [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post) . Basically, make it as easy as possible for somebody to help you by supplying data so it does not have to be typed by hand by the user.

Comment: Remember to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78186708/edit) your question to add things like this.

Comment: Thanks Alan. I added the table for your perusal along with the explanations of what I would the data to look like.

Comment: OK good, a few more questions. Is the table you showed the results of a pivot? If so then the base data is more useful as this is probably easier to solve in the query. Finally, are you expecting a chart with 3 columns, showing values of 2, 2 and 1 respectively?

Comment: No, that table was not a pivot, but I did one in ssrs report just to see who had 3 or 2 or 1 record. Yes, I'm expecting a chart with only 3 columns showing values of 3, 2 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

This is much easier to do in the dataset query, so that's the approach taken here.

First get your sample data *(this is the kind of thing its useful to add to the post as a db-fiddle so others can copy it in and have data ready to play with)*

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (StaffRef int, OT2122 int, OT2223 int, OT2324 int)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
(15088, 1, 0, 0),
(15088, 0, 1, 0),
(15088, 0, 0, 1),
(15157, 0, 1, 0),
(15157, 0, 0, 1),
(20622, 0, 0, 1),
(20454, 0, 1, 0),
(20454, 0, 0, 1),
(20465, 1, 0, 0),
(20465, 0, 1, 0),
(20465, 0, 0, 1)

SELECT StaffRecCount, StaffCount  = COUNT(*)
    FROM 
        (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            StaffRef
            , StaffRecCount = SUM(OT2122+OT2223+OT2324) OVER (PARTITION BY StaffRef) FROM @t
        ) rc
GROUP BY StaffRecCount
```

The query at the end takes the sample data, sums the 3 columns for each `StaffRef` and then the outer query takes these results and groups them by the counts in the inner query.

It's a pain as it's hard coded to columns but that's all I had to go on. I suspect the data is held in a more normalised form somewhere and if it is it will make things easier... anyway...

The end result is a very simple dataset that looks like this.

| StaffRecCount | StaffCount |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |

Now we just add a simple column chart and setup as follows... Also set the sort order of the Category Group to be in reverse so the results are 3,2,1

[image]

Final output looks like this... (needs a bit of tidying but close enough)

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much Alan. I'm afraid I have nearly 600 Staff Ref and nearly 900 rows and they are being added continually as more data is being pulled in. Does this approach mean I would have to manually update this table? Could I draw this bit 'FROM @t
        ) rc' from the existing data?

Comment: exactly, that part was simply to get the sample data you supplied to demo how to build the query and chart. Basically @t represents you current table/view results. If you current data sits in a single table then it's as simple as swapping out @t with your table name (and obviously deleting the table declaration and insert into code)